# blake2b256 hash function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hash

I am working on 1 project that need to use the blake2b256 hash function, but the project is written in Swift and as I try to find the library or out source, there seems nothing for me. Is that possible to implement the function of blake2b256 in Swift or just my project has to fail?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I find it myself.
https://github.com/tesseract-one/Blake2.swift
That's the answer for generating blake2b. I have checked again with php version for blake2b and swift and php give the same result for same input.

Comment: Please keep the answer section for explanations and sample codes; if you simply want to submit links to other pages with the solution, these can find a better place in the comments section.

Comment: Please keep the answer section for explanations and sample codes; if you simply want to submit links to other pages with the solution, these can find a better place in the comments section.